# Importing Existing Struts 1 application Developed using MyEclipse to Intellij IDEA 15.0.3

Tags: java, intellij-idea, struts, struts-1

I am trying to import a project developed with MyEclipse 6.0 IDE into Intellij 15.0.3.

I am unable to import the following packages

```
import javax.ejb.CreateException;
import javax.ejb.EJBHome;
```

Trying to download JEE 6 jars with IntelliJ I get the error:

```
 
Failed to download 'http://download.jetbrains.com/idea/j2ee_libs/JavaEE/6/javax.annotation.jar':Cannot download 'http://download-cf.jetbrains.com/idea/j2ee_libs/JavaEE/6/javax.annotation.jar':Connection closed at byte 969. Expected 7713 bytes. response: 200 OK
```

[image: Intellij Error]

Comment: Can you type the error in? It hard to read in the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comp on which you develop should be connected to internet to allow outgoing connections. If you are using proxy to connect to internet then check the proxy settings in the browser. Below is the button that you can use to configure proxy settings to allow IDEA to connect to the internet.

The file

```
http://download.jetbrains.com/idea/j2ee_libs/JavaEE/6/javax.annotation.jar
```

is downloadable from the browser, just copy/paste it to the navigator bar and start downloading.